# compilation issues for neo4j-graph-api, neo4j-logging, neo4j-procedure-api with neo4j 4.3.2

Tags: java, neo4j, compilation

I have upgraded to neo4j 4.3.2 community version. This brings in other neo4J packages like neo4j-graph-api, neo4j-logging, neo4j-procedure-api,neo4j-resource all 4.3.2. However it throw compilation error for neo4j-garph-api related classes. Error thrown is:

\org.neo4j\neo4j-graphdb-api\4.3.2\5c61e5a720893ca4a114c92aa7f256375e87edf5\neo4j-graphdb-api-
4.3.2.jar(org/neo4j/graphdb/Label.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Similar error are thrown for classes from neo4j-logging 4.3.2 and neo4j-procedure-api 4.3.2, neo4j-resource 4.3.2 etc

Downgrading these packages individually works. I would assume as all these sub-packages also have their own 4.3.2 version, that should make it compatible with the latest neo4j version.
What is going wrong? Have I missed something here?

Partial Dependency tree
[image]

Comment: Upgrading to 4.3.2 from which version? Were you using a JDK 8? You need a JDK 11 for 4.x.

Comment: From 3.2. I am using Java 11

Comment: Can you please include the dependency tree in your question?

Comment: @fbiville does this attached image help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The main problem was 'class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0'. This is caused when the Jar that I have included in the project was compiled with Java 11. The person who compiled that Jar could have used Java 11 only features and hence had to generate the bytecode that is only compatible with JDK 11 or higher.

My IDE was using java 8. When I changed my IDE to use Java 11, it compiled the project.